# Why is my SQL Server backup file so large?

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014 Enterprise (Active/Passive) on two virtual servers. I have backup script as follows and it runs each night at midnight:

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @FileDate VARCHAR(2000)
SET @FileDate = cast(
  cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as varchar) +    -- get the year
  right('0' + cast (datepart(month,getdate()) as varchar),2) + --get the month and zero pad
  right('0' + cast (datepart(day,getdate()) as varchar),2)   --get the day and zero pad
as numeric(10,0))  -- convert back to a numeric(10,0) 
SET @FilePath = 'H:\SQLBak\my_database_' + @FileDate + '.bak' --CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 110) +'.bak'



BACKUP DATABASE [my_database] 
TO  DISK = @FilePath WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'my_database-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

It generates backups such as `my_database_20160515.bak`

I am able to find `my_database.mdf` on the server, which is about 14M. I am also able to find `my_database.ldf` and it is about 265M.

The above backup script always generates a backup file with the size similar to that of the `.LDF` file. How can I generate a backup file with the size just similar to the `.MDF` file? At this moment, I don't care about the database restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this moment, I dont care about the database restore.

Then why make a backup? Even more - why backup the ldf?

Go to simple model and make a full backup. Log will stay empty and you get a daily snapshot (which you actually do not need because making a backup when you not care about a restore is futile).

Comment: Hi TomTom, thanks for your input! The database was set up by someone who left. How can I make the database work in "simple model"? Thanks, again.

Comment: Change the backup model in the database properties.